# YouTube v3 data API abuse through a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am developing an app with the use of the youtube data api. Everything worked well for more than two months until today. I have got a quota limit exceeded error today and after I opened the google cloud console, I noticed that I somehow got over 70 million requests from the chrome app oauth client which is definitely unnormal. Looks like someone is abusing my extension and sending requests.

I do use the `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` and request `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet&mine=true&access_token=${token}` when a token is updated so that I could display the user's authorized account name (and other details) in the extension control panel.

I assume that someone programmatically revokes the access and reloads the extension thousands times a minute so that the extension keeps sending the requests to get the user's channel info.

How do I have to handle such situations correctly? Is there a way to find that user an ban him from using the extension?

Comment: My recommendation is to file a report to Google through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/). They know who is the culprit. In the mean time, delete your credentials data for to stop that illicit activity.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that? I have created an issue but I do not get any choices in the `component` section.

Comment: Remove the OAuth 2.0 Client ID that you pass on to [`chrome.identity.getAuthToken`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-getAuthToken) from with Google Cloud Console on the [Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) page corresponding to your respective project.